# authorize.net - Automated Recurring Billing (ARB) change status inactive to active?

Tags: node.js, authorize.net

is there any way to change **Automated Recurring Billing (ARB)** subscription status inactive to active using authorize node.js sdk.

Comment: There is not an "inactive" status for Authorize.Net ARB. Could you be more specific using the available status messages listed in the [documentation](http://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/features/recurring_billing.html): 
- Suspended
- Expired
- Canceled
- Terminated

Comment: okay, Once i've Canceled my ARB subscription, after that i can active that my ARB subscription ?! Thanks for your replay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A canceled subscription cannot be reactivated. However, if you use `ARBGetSubscriptionRequest` for the cancelled subscription, the response will include a customer profile which you can use to create a [new subscription](http://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/#recurring-billing-create-a-subscription-from-customer-profile).